# Update SQL Server via MS Access Routine (Inner Join Error)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, inner-join

I've taken a query from MS Access that updates a sql server table via an inner join with another table.  The Query works perfectly via ms access interface.

When copy the syntax into vb.net and try and run the routine via a vb.net interface I keep receiving an error referencing to keyword near 'Inner'.

Here is the problem in the simplest form:

```
Table_A:
Field_Id (Auto) 
FieldX_Id (Integer)

Table_B:
Field_Id (Auto)
FieldX_Id (Integer)
FieldLink_Id (Integer)
```

Example:

```
Table_A:

Field_Id = 1

FieldX_Id = 0

Table_B:

Field_Id = 2

FieldX_Id = 1234

FieldLink_Id =1
```

Object:

```
Update Table_A (Set FieldX_Id = 1234)
```

Syntax from Query:

```
UPDATE Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B 
ON Table_A.FieldLink_Id = Table_B.Field_Id
SET Table_A.FieldX_Id = [Table_B].[FieldX_Id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

```
UPDATE ta
SET FieldX_Id = tb.[FieldX_Id]
FROM Table_A ta
JOIN Table_B tb
  ON tb.FieldLink_Id = ta.[Field_Id];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're joining upon the condition:

```
ON Table_A.FieldLink_Id = Table_B.Field_Id
```

But according to your tables structure, `Table_A` does not have a column called `FieldLink_Id`. Perhaps you should change it to:

```
ON Table_A.Field_Id = Table_B.FieldLink_Id
```